# Submit app to AppStore which have aes encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, appstore-approval

I develop IOS app, using swift 3. I use CryptoSwift (https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) in my project to decrypt files from server. Is any problems when submit my app to AppStore? Or what should I prepare before submit app which is have encryption code.

Comment: Hi @YunCHEN have you tried to submit encryption code to store? Because my team said it will be problem.

Comment: Please read the [Export Compliance](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Export%20Compliance#70754944) section of the iTunes Connect FAQ *you need to be logged into iTunes Connect to view that link).

Comment: @YunCHEN There is a lot you must do if your app uses any form of encryption. Please see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: hi @rmaddym, I just read that FAQ, I wanna ask you what is "compliance documents" and where can I find it?

Comment: @rmaddy, you are right. I delete the wrong comment.